# Best way for implement multiple TableviewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Which is the best way to implement multiple `UITableViewCell` 
I have tableview which do have three section one for notification holds switch in `UITableViewCell`, another edit profile shows the username and disclosure & third one static information.

So create three `UITableViewCell`, three section holds items `["notification","editProfile","userInfo"]`

Each section holds multiple Items `[["enable"],["changeItem","changeName"],["mobile","name","age"]]`

In CellForRowAt index the old process use if/else condition to display the team differently which works fine.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstTableCell") as! FirstTableCell
        // Set up cell.label
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondTableCell") as! SecondTableCell
        // Set up cell.button
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "thirdTableCell") as! ThirdTableCell
        // Set up cell.textField
        return cell
    }
}
```

I would like to know the best procedure for implenting in this case.

Comment: At first thought, I would create an array of arrays. Each array would represents each section. Then, I would create an enum which includes each possible item. Finally, in the tableView `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I would do a switch on the enum to know which cell I have to implement.

Comment: The code you posted is fine. What is it you are unsure of?

Comment: First, I’d move the code for configuring the cells into the cell subclasses to avoid cluttering the `cellForRowAt`. Second, I’d transition the model from arrays of arrays of strings to custom types for which the values would be self-evident. We can probably show how to clean this up, but your model isn’t entirely clear so it’s hard to get more specific. I might suggest posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Rob This question looks like it's lacking in code already. Whatever you do don't post an MCVE at Code Review as that will only get downvoted and closed. If you do want to post a question like this at Code Review you should ensure you include everything you want reviewed, and everything is working as intended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194910/discussion-between-rob-and-peilonrayz).